# Route form post data to index PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

In the application im building ive made it possible to route all incoming page requests through my index file using the below .htaccess code

**.htaccess file**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect /index.php to / (optional, but recommended I guess)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php
RewriteRule ^index.php/?(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]

# Run everything else but real files through index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
```

This works flawlessly and ive actually been able to build a basic framework from using this. Now my problem is that im trying to post a form from one of my pages but obviously because everything is being redirected to index i dont have access to the $_POST data.

This is the result of using `die(var_dump($_POST))` on my index page or any other page:

`array(0){} //basically an empty array`

Below is an example of the form im using to post the data:

```
<form action="{{ url('about') }}" method="POST">
    <input type="text" value="name"><br>
    <input type="text" value="password"><br>
    <button>Submit Form</button>
</form>
```

**My Question**

Is there a way to redirect post data to my index file so it can be handled there? Or is there another method i should be using here?

Edit:

It seems that the only reason this didnt work for me was because my form inputs didnt have named values on them.. adding a name to input tags on the form allowed me to use the post data...

Comment: Not an answer to your question specifically but have you considered using a framework (i.e. - Laravel, Symfony, CodeIgniter, Yii, etc.).  Every one that I've had any experience with will get you set-up with a front controller as you're describing as fast as composer can install it.

Comment: @alaric I use laravel currently, im building my own framework as a massive learning curve and tbh its working, its literally priceless to PHP knowledge when using it to make something like a framework

Comment: Ah, fair enough.  I did the same in the past as a means of becoming more acquainted with various design patterns.  Here's a brief article which may be useful at least as a starting point: https://www.sitepoint.com/front-controller-pattern-1/

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is in the index.php file pass in the post data to the function or other system that loads your page.

Obviously this greatly depends on how you are setting up your framework so can't go into much more detail.

In my own framework I created (for the same reason as yourself) I had my central index file and that calls my 'Front Controller' class and passes in any post data. The front controller deals with loading the page content and passing the post data to the functions that needs it.

Hope that helps

Comment: Hmm thanks for this, since im basically setting this up off the top of my head ive not really looked into a front controller but this sounds good, only problem is im not sure how to get the post data from a form to page other than that in its action field

Comment: @YasminFrench Do you use multiple directories to organise the php files on your website? Like having about.php in an about directory.